# Retrieving ViewModel using SwiftUI and Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, viewmodel

I am currently retrieving  data from Firebase (a list of stories) but am receiving an error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" on the db.collection line of code. It doesn't stop the build but is something I need to fix, thank you for any help

```
class StoriesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var stories = [Stories]()
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func getStories() {
        db.collection("GBnews").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot?, error: Error?) in
            
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching news stories: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                    print("No Documents")
                    return
                }

            self.stories = documents.compactMap { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Stories? in
                 return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Stories.self)
             }

            // Sort events by date (oldest last)
            self.stories.sort { (event1: Stories, event2: Stories) -> Bool in
                return event1.date > event2.date
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is likely a typo somewhere. Comment out portions until you find it

Comment: This compiles just fine for me. Note that you don't actually need to provide the types for querySnapshot and error, so `.addSnapshotListener { [weak self] (querySnapshot, error) in` is perfectly fine. I might also sort the result of  `compactMap` *before* assigning it to `self.stories` to avoid extra UI updates